# Problemas ao criar um modal reutilizavel

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

- HTML

//Eu pego o que tem dentro da classe `observacoes` e jogo pra uma `textarea` dentro do modal

```
                <td>
                    <div class="observacoes">teste</div>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-modal-comentario" data-obs-id="{{ $lista->user_id }}">Adicionar/Atualizar Comentários</button>
                </td>
```

- Meu Modal

// Dentro dele vai ser criado um botão dinamicamente (`Atualizar Comentário` e vai ter uma `textarea` com o texto da observações e será editável)

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-conteudo"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="modal-buttons">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- Jquery

//Um botão de atualizar será criado dinamicamente e uma textarea dentro do modal

```
        $(document.body).on("click", "#btn-modal-update", function(){
            var $modal = "#modal-1";
            alert($($modal).find("textarea").text());
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
                },
                url: "{{ URL::to('lista-contatos/update') }}",
                data: {
                    "id": get_id,
                    "observacao": $($modal).find("textarea").text()
                },
                type: "POST",
                success: function(result){

                }
            });
        });
        $(document.body).on("click",".btn-modal-comentario", function(){
            var $modal = "#modal-1";
            get_id = $(this).data("obs-id");
            var obs = $(this).closest("td").find(".observacoes").text();

            $($modal).find(".modal-body").html("<textarea class='form-control' id='teste'>"+obs+"</textarea>");
            $($modal).find(".modal-footer").html("<button class='btn btn-primary' id='btn-modal-update'>Atualizar Observação</button>");
            $($modal).modal('show');

        });
```

O problema é que não está pegando o valor atualizado corretamente depois que você digita qualquer coisa na `textarea`, o texto gerado é sempre `"teste"`.

Answer (score 0):

O problema esta ocorrendo por que você em nenhum momento esta atualizando o html original, então esta pegando sempre o mesmo valor...

Segue abaixo o código corrigido e funcionando, veja explicações nos comments do código:

```js
// definir uma global para guardar o elemento de retorno
var observacoes;

         $(document.body).on("click", "#btn-modal-update", function(){
            var textarea = $(this).parents('.modal').find("textarea").text(); // selecione o textarea no modal em que esta o botão clicado, caso reutilize o código ou modifique o id do modal isso não será problema
            console.log(textarea);
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
                },
                url: "{{ URL::to('lista-contatos/update') }}",
                data: {
                    "id": get_id,
                    "observacao": textarea
                },
                type: "POST",
                success: function(result){
                  // atualizar o valor no html original
                  observacoes.html(textarea); // variável global com o elemento original
                }
            });
          // deixar aqui fora só aqui no teste       
          observacoes.html(textarea); // variável global com o elemento original         
        });
        $(document.body).on("click",".btn-modal-comentario", function(){
            var $modal = $('#modal-1'); // guarde na variável o elemento e não a str de seleção
            get_id = $(this).data("obs-id");
            observacoes = $(this).siblings(".observacoes"); // guardar o elemento na variável global para atualizar depois
            $modal.find(".modal-body").html("<textarea class='form-control' id='teste'>"+observacoes.html()+"</textarea>");
            $modal.find(".modal-footer").html("<button class='btn btn-primary' id='btn-modal-update' data-dismiss='modal'>Atualizar Observação</button>");
            $modal.modal('show');

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12">
  <h1></h1>
<div class="well">
                    <div class="observacoes">teste</div>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-modal-comentario" data-obs-id="{{ $lista->user_id }}">Adicionar/Atualizar Comentários</button>
</div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-conteudo"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="modal-buttons">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```